# How can I check a button has preventDefault property or not?

Tags: jquery

I validate a form by one js file. If this validation is succeeded then it will remove preventDefault property as follows:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".normalForm button", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
       if(noError){
                    $(this).closest('form').unbind('submit').submit();
                }

});
```

Here noError has Boolean value true or false. If error exist its value is false otherwise its value is true.I do not show all codes due to simplicity. My code works fine. But after this validation succeeded I want to prevent normal submission again. I want to do this by 'start_chat' id as follows:

```
  $('#start_chat').click(function(){
// here I want to check if preventDefault is removed or not 
});
```

In this situation $('#start_chat').click(function(){ and $(document).on("click", ".normalForm button", function (event) refer same button.

My concern is: how to check if preventDefault is removed or not. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried [event.isDefaultPrevented()](http://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/)?

Comment: This sounds **really** convoluted. With more context, I'm sure we could help you find a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`event.isDefaultPrevented()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/) to find out whether or not the default behaviour has been prevented.

http://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/

```
$('#start_chat').click(function(event){
   if (event.isDefaultPrevented()){
     alert("Default behaviour prevented");
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but the default wasn't prevented on the event the OP's looking to check (the later click).